# How to change first row values of csv file?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, csv, typeerror

I am trying to change all negative values to 0 in excel files.

However, it seems like the pandas skips the first row.

Please help me with preventing skip issue! Thank you.

## Here is the code:

```
# importing pandas module
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv("FAPI-N2-rere_2D_modified.csv")

df[df < 0 ] = 0

df.to_csv('FAPI-N2-rere_2D_modified2.csv')
```

==========================================================

I have tried to add some codes into the above,

```
# importing pandas module
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv("FAPI-N2-rere_2D_modified.csv", **header = None**)

df[df < 0 ] = 0

df.to_csv('FAPI-N2-rere_2D_modified2.csv')
```

However, i keep getting the typeerror:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I would be so much appreciated if anyone could please help me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: please share sample of the csv

Answer (score 0):

Some columns of your dataframe contains strings.
If their content is numeric you can try to convert them into numeric datatype, here it is explained how to do that:
[Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)

If you have columns containing strings, you need to replace your negative values only on numeric columns.